# Bizzare BitVector query slowness in presence of arrays

Tags: z3

Running in a bizarre behavior with the following query:

```
(declare-const M1 (Array Int Int))
(declare-const M2 (Array Int Int))

; Unrelated assertion. Comment it out, and the query returns unsat instantly.
(assert (= M1 M2)) 

(declare-const CB32 (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-const CA32 (_ BitVec 32))

(declare-const CA16 (_ BitVec 16))
(declare-const CB16 (_ BitVec 16))
(declare-const VA16 (_ BitVec 16))
(declare-const VB16 (_ BitVec 16))

(assert (= CA16 VA16))
(assert (= CB16 VB16))
(assert (= CA32 ((_ sign_extend 16) CA16)))
(assert (= CB32 ((_ sign_extend 16) CB16)))

(assert (not (= ((_ extract 15 0) (bvmul CA32 CB32)) (bvmul VA16 VB16))))
(check-sat)
```

If you comment the first assert, the query returns unsat immediately. If you leave it in, it ran for at least 10h before I killed it. The puzzling part is, that the commented-out assert is not even related to the unsatisfiable predicate, nor any other predicate, and is trivially satisfiable. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Z3 uses two different engines in these cases: 
For formulas that only use bit-vectors, it uses a much more efficient engine.
For formulas that mix several theories, it uses a general purpose engine that is less efficient for bit-vector constraints.